# Modal View Controller State Restoration SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller, uiscenedelegate

I am trying to restore a modal `Viewcontroller` from within `SceneDelegate`.

However this code doesn't allow the modal view controller to display and causes the following **error:** `"Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for...".`

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    if let userActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities.first ?? session.stateRestorationActivity {
        // Restoring Data and Modal VC:

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
        let splitController =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "splitVC") 
        if let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
             splitController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
             self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
             navigationController.present(splitController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    } else {
        print("No User Activity")
        // Loads Initial VC
    }

}
```

Any ideas as how to fix this and present a modal `Viewcontroller` from the `SceneDelegate`

Comment: You don't need to unwrap the view controller.

Comment: hi @dgee4. Were you able to solve this problem? I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to load a new UIViewController before the one presenting it finishes animating. You should simply call the presentation asynchronously on the main thread:

> `DispatchQueue.main.async {
>     navigationController.present(splitController, animated: false, completion: nil)
>   }`